# Do something after promises looping through an array and fulfilling, react javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

Most of the other questions don't account for doing something after Promises.all. Also, my situation might be strange.

Promise.all still lets the below run multiple times. But I only want doSomethingWithResults(results) to happen once all iterations are finished.

I am forced to use a promises here so I need to find a solution to "awaiting" all promises to finish.

```
const [results, setResults] = useState([])

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const promises = [];

    stuff.map((thing) => {
      const thisIsAPromise = digitaloceantask.something(thing)
      promises.push(thisIsAPromise);
      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
         () => {
        dosomething
        .then((thing) => {
              setResults((prevState) => [...prevState, result]);
            });
         })
        }
      );
      const result = Promise.all(promises)
     }
      doSomethingWithResults(results) // This happens multiple times, instead of waiting for all promises to finish. Would an if statement help?
})
```

Comment: `promsie.on` ??? promises don't have an `on` ... perhaps, since the callback is `async` you should be `await`ing something in there? also, why are you using `.map` since you don't care about the returned array of undefined? use `.forEach`

Comment: Can you show your actual code? What actually needs to be done to accomplish what you want depends on what's actually in the `doSomething` and `stuffHappenedHere` sections

Comment: your `doSomethingWithResults(results) is INSIDE the `.map` - so of course it happens multiple times, once every time the .map callback is called .... also `const result` is never used, so why do you even have that line - I think your real code and code you posted are almost completely different

Comment: your edit has only added to the confusion ... `promises.push(promise)` ... what is `promise`? your map callback is still `async` for no reason, and you're STILL calling `doSomethingWithResults` every iteration

Comment: is `uploadTask` really a Promise? or at least a "thenable" .. I think you've fallen into the trap where you think the `async` keyword performs some magical transformation on ALL asynchronous code ... it does not ... `async` (and `await` - which go hand in hand, and you almost NEVER need to use `async` without it) is syntactic "sugar" for Promises, one tiny part of javascript that is asynchronous, not just anything that is asynchronous

Comment: Yes it is ".thenable", I removed the async because I probably can't use `await` to wait for all promises of the iteration to finish

Comment: Yes, you can ... by the way you're missing `)` before `doSomethingWithResults(results)` ... and `const result = Promise.all(promises)` does nothing at all useful, since you never use result

Comment: when does `uploadTask` resolve?

Comment: maybe something like https://pastebin.com/SiY4C5JS - I think that's closer without knowing the details of the thenable

Comment: @小红书 it will help if you add documentation of the Digital Ocean function that you're trying to call so we can check what it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, the Promises you're waiting for are the ones from `digitaloceantask.something` - but what you actually need is the ones you get from calling `.getDownloadURL`, which needs to be returned up the chain somehow. Although `.getDownloadURL` looks to return a Promise, it's unfortunately nested inside a callback, so you'll need to construct a Promise that resolves when the callback runs.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    Promise.all(stuff.map((thing) => new Promise((resolve) => {
        digitaloceantask
            .something(thing)
            .on(
                "state_changed",
                () => storage()
                    .ref("something")
                    .child(something.name)
                    .getDownloadURL() // 2 images
                    .then(resolve)
                    // can an error handler be added here? .catch(reject)?
            );
    })))
        .then((newResults) => {
            setResults(newResults); // or setResults([...results, ...newResults]);
            doSomethingWithResults(newResults)
        });
    // .catch(handleErrors); // don't forget this part, if it might reject
};
```

Another approach, if you're updating other state during this, would be to have an effect hook that runs when the `results` state updates.

```
then((newResults) => {
    setResults(newResults); // or setResults([...results, ...newResults]);
});
// .catch(handleErrors); // don't forget this part
```

and

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (results.length) {
        doSomethingWithResults(results);
    }
}, [results]);
```

Using that method instead can be easier if you have other state updates and need `doSomethingWithResults` to reference values from the most recent render.

Comment: assuming `.on(` only gets called ONCE ... the comment `// 2 images` suggests that may not be the case - I wonder if there's `.on('done` or similar to indicate when `digitaloceantask.something(thing)` is complete

Comment: I will review this, then check mark accordingly